# Blackberry buffered playback demo?

Tags: networking, blackberry, audio-streaming, mmapi

Can someone help me to buffer a mp3 file on a server using the Blackberry buffered playback demo app provided with the jde?

I have loaded it in the simulator and my mds is started but I'm unable to play the audio.
There is no error but it doesn't play/load.
The code looks all fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This may help:](http://www.ericgiguere.com/blackberry/http-issues.html)

> **Blackberry Enterprise Server Limitations**
>
> By default, the BlackBerry Enterprise Server (BES) limits the response size of a single HTTP response to 128K. If you try to fetch anything bigger your application will receive a 413 (Request Entity Too Large) response code. To get around this you must use the BES management console to change the value of the Maximum number of kilobytes per connection field to a higher value, up to 1024K.
>
> Note that this limit also applies to the MDS simulator, so you'll need to change the simulator's settings as well. Edit the mds\config\rimpublic.property file in your JDE installation directory and change the value of the IPPP.connection.MaxNumberOfKBytesToSend property to match the BES setting and then restart the simulator.

Also check if you [using correct ip instead of localhost](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/117869-http-error-403-forbidden-while-accessing-http-localhost-iis-blackberry.html)

In the end you might want to check file in Blackberry browser before open it in app, don't forget to enable streaming in browser settings.